# Moment lemma for circular arc polygons

Tags: discrete-geometry

A "moment lemma" originally due to Fejes Tóth (I guess) states that if $P$ is any polygon (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) with $k$ sides, then for any $\mathbf{y}$, we have $\int_P\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} \geq \int_U \|\mathbf{x}\|^2\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$, where $U$ is the regular $k$-gon with the same area as $P$ centered at the origin. I was wondering if there is a similar result (my literature survey did not produce any useful references) if $P$ is a circular-arc polygon. That is, if $P$ is the intersection of the interior or exterior of $k$ disks with arbitrary radii (the final lower bound will then obviously depend on these radii). The original moment lemma would then perhaps be -informally- a special case where these disks have infinite radii. I am also aware of the classical lower bound: If $\mathcal{E}$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (measurable etc), then $\int_E \|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} \geq \int_D \|\mathbf{x}\|^2\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$, where $D$ is the disk with the same area as $E$ with center origin, but this bound is too weak for my purposes.

Comment: The disc is a circular arc polygon, according to your definition. So the "classical lower bound" which you cite in the end seems to answer your question. If not, please state what your conjecture is.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko You are right. I in fact had a more precise setup in mind, ...

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko But did not write it down to keep the discussion simple.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Let me then edit it hopefully soon so as to avoid the degenerate cases that you have mentioned.